# Finding the range of $f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to find what is the range of this function $$f(x) = \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1}$$

I try to isolate $x$ in terms of $y$, but I obtain a fourth-degree function and I don't know what to do next.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hint: Let $t=\sqrt{1-x}$, then simplify the expression.

Comment: @Feng Thank´s for the answer. I obtain the same fourth degree function and I do not what to do with that.

Comment: @AlexanderRios One should obtain $\frac{1}{t(t^2-2)}$ after simplifying. Would that help?

Comment: I obtain $y = \frac{t}{(1-t^2)^2 -1}$

Comment: @AlexanderRios that is correct, tidy it up and cancel the $t$.

Comment: Ok. Now I have $y = \frac{1}{t(t^2-2)}$ then if I try to solve for $t$ I obtain $t^3 - 2t -1/y=0$ ¿Is it correct? or ¿What have I to do? Sorry, I am confused.

Comment: Well now you have to think about how the value of $y$ changes as $t$ changes. Of course, you also need to figure out what values of $t$ are allowed. @AlexanderRios

Answer (score 3):

Get a feel for the behaviour of $f$. We have $x<-1$ or $-1<x<1$,
$$ \lim _{x\to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1} = 0,\quad \lim _{x\to -1-} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1} = +\infty,\quad \lim _{x\to -1+} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1} = -\infty,\quad \lim _{x\to 1-} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1} = -\infty.$$
Continuity in $(-\infty,-1)$ implies that $(0,\infty) \subseteq \mathrm{ran}f$.

Since the limits $x\to -1+$ and $x\to 1-$ both are $-\infty$ we should find
$$ \sup _{x\in (-1,1)} \frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x^2-1}. $$
Derivative test shows there's local maximum at $x_0=1/3$, hence
$$ \mathrm{ran}f = \left(-\infty, f(x_0) \right] \cup (0,\infty). $$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to find the range trying to isolate the x in terms o y?  Cause I am in a basic precalculous class and I do not work with terms like limits and derivate tests yet.

Comment: @AlexanderRios For $x<-1$ the function is invertible, so writing $x=x(y)$ could work. But for $x\in (-1,1)$, $f$ is not invertible, so the same trick won't work. Next to eyeballing it from the graph, I don't know how to make progress without evaluating certain limits at some point in the argument.